# Algorithm or math to project a GIF file size?

Tags: objective-c, image, compression, gif, animated-gif

I have a user's animated gif file that is about 10mb. I'd like to allow users to upload it and let me host it on my server, but I'd like to rescale it to fit a maximum file size of 5mb to conserve bandwidth from hotlinking.

I have a basic method right now that determines a `targetWidth` and `targetHeight` based on pixel surface area.

It works well enough:

```
    CGFloat aspectRatio = originalHeight / originalWidth;
    CGFloat reductionFactor = desiredFileSize / originalFileSize;
    CGFloat targetSurfaceArea = originalSurfaceArea * reductionFactor;

    int targetHeight = targetSurfaceArea / sqrt(targetSurfaceArea/aspectRatio);
    int targetWidth = targetSurfaceArea / targetHeight;
```

Its fairly accurate, ex. results: a 27mb file will turn into 3.3mb, or a 13.9mb will turn into 5.5mb.

I would like to tune this accuracy to get much closer to 5mb, and I was hoping someone would know a bit more about how gif color / frame count could better be factored into this algorithm. Thanks

Comment: are you want to resize size of your image ? so its may be decrease file size also >?

Comment: @iPatel yes, I'm trying to reduce filesize by resizing the image. I would like to solve for 5mb = width and height

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you're going to find an easy way to do this. Projecting the compressed size of a file without running the compression algorithm seems to me to be non deterministic.

However, if you have plenty of compute cycles you could use an [approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation) based approach. Use the algorithm above to give you a first resize of the image. If the resulting file is > than 5Mb, half the resize percentage and try again. If < 5Mb add 50% to the resize percentage and try again. Repeat until you get sufficiently close to 5Mb.

So, for example

```
50% = 3.3Mb, so try halfway between 50 and 100
75% = 6.1Mb, so try halfway between 75 and 50
62.5% = 4.7Mb so try halfway between 62.5 and 75
```

etc